# Azureml - Why my environment image build status is always "already exists"

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk, azuremlsdk

I'm using custom Dockerfile to create environment for Azure machine learning. However everytime I run my code, I always get back "already exists" on the UI for my environment. I didn't find much documentation on this status which is why I'm asking here.

I assume that this means that an image with the same dockerfile exists in my container registry. What I don't get is: if the image already exits why my environment is unusable and set to this.

To create my environment I use this snippet:

```
ws = Workspace.from_config()
env  = Environment.from_dockerfile(environment_name, f"./environment/{environment_name}/Dockerfile")
env.python.user_managed_dependencies = True
env.register(ws)
env.build(ws)
```

Am I doing something wrong there?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

By default, all the environments will be working on Linux machine as it is from the docker image. With respect to the issue, we need to clear the cache of the images and then restart the run. Check out the below
syntaxes which need to be used.

`docker-compose build --no-cache` -> to clear the cache
and don't forget to restart the most updated image

```
docker-compose up -d <service> --force-recreate
```

The issue will be resolved. It might be because of the cache.

Checkout the documentation to check and recreate the entire operation. [Link](https://medium.com/microsoftazure/how-to-create-custom-docker-base-images-for-azure-machine-learning-environments-86aa4c7bc7b9)

With respect to UI. Create the DevOps image with Inference clusters.

[image]

[image]

[image]